# Yii - CActive record - How to work around server query cache

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii, query-cache

I am using the Yii framework for my webapp (wich makes use of ACtiveRecord).
At the back of ACtiveRecord the framework manages all queries from the database.

My problem is I am on a shared server, and it turns out the server has query cache enabled which is a pain in the S. I really need to get around the query cache.
FlUSH would not work for me, because I don't have RELOAD privilege.

If I had used each ActiveRecord database fetch as a crude mySQL query , I guess I could have set the query itself in such a way which disables cache, like using the NO_CACHE tag, or using a false query term which involves the current timestamp (resulting in each query being different query text).

My question to you guys is what is the best way to do it with the Yii/ActiveRecord scheme.
Can I change the implementation of the findAll() function? 
I have a subclass of CActiveRecord, So if there's something I can do there it would be perfect.

Sorry for the long question.
Ilan

Answer (score 1):

**Default Scope**

A model class can have a default scope that would be applied for all queries (including relational ones) about the model. To do so, we override the CActiveRecord::defaultScope method as follows,

```
class Content extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function defaultScope()
    {
        return array(
            'condition'=>"1<='".time()."'",
        );
    }
}
```

**Note:** Default scope and named scopes only apply to SELECT queries. They are ignored for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries. Also, when declaring a scope (default or named), the AR class cannot be used to make DB queries in the method that declares the scope.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes